# Does IIS allow the client to use a server certificate as client certificate?

Tags: ssl, iis, mtls

This is a follow-up question of [Use Server Certificate As Client Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893917/use-server-certificate-as-client-certificate). I know that you SHOULD use client certificate for client authentication. It seems that some servers allow the client to present a certificate that is actually a "server certificate" (OID - 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1).

My question is particularly whether IIS allow that? Is there a configuration that decides this behaviour?

Comment: If IIS ever allowed that, Microsoft customers might have reported such as bugs a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Client authentication vs server authentication is different processes. these two types of certificates have very specific purposes, and they cannot be used in place of one another.

A server certificate is used to authenticate the server's identity to the client and perform encryption on data-in-transit to assure data confidentiality.

A client certificate is used to authenticate the client or user identity to the server and does not encrypt any data, it only serves as a more secure authentication mechanism than passwords.

Comment: It is a server implementation detail. I know some servers (arguably not strictly following the RFCs) do allow that. That is why I am asking in particular whether IIS allows that and if it does is there a configuration for it.

Comment: It is impossible to do in iis.

Comment: Again, the server certificate cannot be used as a client certificate.

Comment: Sorry, I read your previous comment wrong :)